# Where I can check the roadmap/vision development for any Ubuntu application?

Tags: software-center, application-development

Ubuntu Software Center is supposed to replace several utilities provided by other piece of software as can be seen in the [rationale](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#Rationale), but I can't find equivalent functionality in Ubuntu Software Center. Where I can find the development plans of Ubuntu Software Center and any other packages included in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general Ubuntu development you may want to check the [Work Items Tracker](http://status.ubuntu.com/). The amount included in this site is overwhelming since it covers all milestones on all aspects of Ubuntu.

The [about page](http://status.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-t/about.html) covers relatively what the site is: every aspect of development and bug targets of the meeting held by the different organs of Ubuntu, like [Ubuntu Developer Submit](https://launchpad.net/uds-project), the [MOTU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU) meetings, and any other [teams](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Teams) are captured, analyzed and tracked here.

Your specific concern is somewhere, about [here](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu?searchtext=software%20center). If it not, then you should try to bring the community attention to that.

Comment: UDS is more about the general big picture of where Ubuntu development is headed, and less about individual applications. Sometimes there are sessions about specific apps, usually about changing a default app and what is needed to make that happen. Blueprints are also not entirely reliable. Anyone can register a blueprint on any project. It does not mean the thing in the blueprint is being worked on, or planned to be added, by the upstreams.

Comment: @Braiam - thanks for the answer, it contains helpful information which I wasn't aware of. I'm not sure though if I can accept it as dobey is actually right that WIT and UDS are more about the general big picture. Interestingly, USC does have a wiki page written by mpt which does have a "roadmap" but I have an impression that this wiki page and actual development targets are in separate universes. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Pavel as you can see, sometimes there are milestones about something specific, sometimes about something general, which is more or less what you are looking for. I don't believe dobey answer because, common, something as big as Ubuntu should have some planning.

Answer (score 0):

You must ask the upstream developers of whichever package you are interested in, what their plans for the software is.

Ubuntu does not maintain a collection of roadmaps and plans for the individual pieces of software that are in the archive.